# Asp.net, oracle sql, Basically search multiple strings in two columns name, prename from textbox with oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, crystal-reports

I have a `textbox`(Nume) and I do a search in oracle sql database and display it in `crystal report`. The question is how can I search from another one column and display it. Like name and prename in the same `textbox` (search multiple strings in multiple columns), in my situation from nume and prenume.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=desktop-2hiivbv;Persist Security Info=True;Password=*****;User ID=STUDENT");
OleDbDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds;
public string strSQl;

protected void Cauta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        strSQl = "select * from angajati where nume ='" + this.ToTitleCase(Nume.Text) + "'";
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQl, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "angajati");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    CrystalReport raport = new CrystalReport();
    raport.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["angajati"]);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = raport;
}
```

the table is this

```
CREATE TABLE angajati (
                        nr_crt int primary key,
                        nume varchar(20) not null,
                        prenume varchar(20) not null
)
```

Comment: Just for a clarification, You have a text box and you want to search multiple columns of your table for text box value right?

Comment: yes @RangaDewasinghe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your SQL query as follows.(I assume your other column is "prename")

```
strSQl = "select * from angajati where nume ='" + this.ToTitleCase(Nume.Text) + "' or prename="+ this.ToTitleCase(Nume.Text) + "';
```

Comment: it's working partial, but if i write name and prename there is no answer...blank @RangaDewasinghe

Comment: @SereDaniel Yeah. This should behave like that. So you want to search multiple strings in multiple columns which are typed on the same textbox then? This will not be possible.
The only thing you can do with this limitations, use SQL LIKE condition.
But it will not be helpful either.

Comment: If we can get multiple search criteria as delimited,Maybe we can write some query for your requirement. @SereDaniel